# in alert clicking ok has go to next page and clicking on cancel has to go to previous page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have a message to be alerted as follows :

If the user clicks on ok button aka accept button the page should be redirected to next page and if the user clicks on go/back button it should redirect to the previous page, Can someone suggest anything on this matter thanks.

At present i need to alert following meesage :

```
if(total < total1){
    alert('Total Grants & Others Spending should be LESS THAN Total State Tourism Office Spend Funding')
    return false;
}
```

Comment: looking for `confirm` instead of `alert` ?

Comment: By "go back to previous page", do you actually mean staying on the current page, or go back one step ?

Comment: go back to previous page

Comment: And by "next page", do you mean a URL, or is there a history indice for the next page, as in the same as clicking the forward button in the browser.

Comment: can we have to buttons in that message like go back and other one accept/continue

Comment: Why don't you try the answers and find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `confirm()`, not `alert()`

```
if(total < total1) {
    var redirect = confirm('Total Grants & Others Spending should be LESS THAN Total State Tourism Office Spend Funding');

    if (redirect) {
         window.location.href = 'nextpage.html';
    }else{
         window.history.back();
         // or window.history.go(-1);
    }
}
```

The History API is only supported in IE10 and up

Comment: excuse me can we give return true in if(redirect){return true;} will it work

Comment: That depends on how this script is called, you didn't post the event handler for the button? Did you just try it and see if it works

Comment: If it's inside the event handler for an anchor, you could do `window.location.href = this.href;`

Comment: if(total < total1) {
    var redirect = confirm('Total Grants & Others Spending should be LESS THAN Total State Tourism Office Spend Funding');

    if (redirect) {
         window.location.href = 'nextpage.html';
    }else{
         return false;window.history.back();
         // or window.history.go(-1);
    }
} can we use like this will it work, because at present it is going to next page when clicked cancel also

Comment: can i have goback and accept buttons instead of ok and cancel

Comment: @user3165411 - No you can't, the text on the buttons of the default confirm is set by the browser, and in the users language etc. so it can't be changed. If you have to change the buttons you'll have to use a custom dialog, like jQuery UI dialog instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (confirm("something")) return true;
else {
  history.back();
  return false;
}
```

assuming a link wired up on click:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("accept").onclick=function() {
    var total = ..., total1=...;
    if (total < total1) {
      if (confirm('Total Grants & Others Spending should be LESS THAN Total State Tourism Office Spend Funding. Continue anyway?')) {
        return true; 
      }
      else { 
        history.back(); 
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true; // total was ok
  }
}
```

using

```
<a href="nextpage.html" id="accept">Accept</a>
```

Comment: is it possible to create a customized confirm message box?

Comment: can i have goback and accept buttons instead of ok and cancel

Comment: Then you need to look into jquery dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use `confirm`.

```
var r = confirm('Total Grants & Others Spending should be LESS THAN Total State Tourism Office Spend Funding');
                if (r == true) {
                    // do if yes,
                } else {
                    // do if no.
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: can i have goback and accept buttons instead of ok and cancel